# Surjectivity of the limit operator: Proof check

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider the operator
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{K}_{n} &:&L^{2}(0,1)\longrightarrow L^{2}(0,1)^{n}, \\
u(x) &\mapsto &A_{n}U_{n}(x)=A_{n}\left( u\left( \frac{x}{n}\right) ,u\left( 
\frac{x+1}{n}\right) ,...,u\left( \frac{x+n-1}{n}\right) \right) ^{t}
\end{eqnarray*}

where $A_{n}$ is $n\times n$ matrix with $\det (A_n)\neq 0,$ $\forall n\geq
1.$

It is clear that $\mathbb{K}_{n}$ is onto since for any $Y\in L^{2}(0,1)^{n}$
the equation $A_{n}U_{n}(x)=Y(x)$ admits a unique solution in $%
L^{2}(0,1)^{n} $ which makes $u$ uniquely determined in this case.

Goal: study the surjectivity of $\mathbb{K}_{\infty}.$

Is well known that $\mathbb{K}_{n}$ is onto if and only if there exists a
constant $C_n>0$ such that
$$
\left\Vert \mathbb{K}_{n}^{\ast }V\right\Vert _{L^{2}(0,1)}^{2}\geq
C_n\left\Vert V\right\Vert _{L^{2}(0,1)^{n}}^{2}.
$$

A simple computation shows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{K}_{n}^{\ast } &:&L^{2}(0,1)^{n}\longrightarrow L^{2}(0,1) \\
V(x) &=&\left( V_{1}(x),...,V_{n}(x)\right) \mapsto
\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}na_{i,j}V_{i}(xn+1-j)\mathbf{1}_{\left( \frac{j-1}{n},\frac{j%
}{n}\right) }(x).
\end{eqnarray*}

Consequently,
$$
\left\Vert \mathbb{K}_{n}^{\ast }V\right\Vert
_{L^{2}(0,1)}^{2}=\int_{0}^{1}\left\Vert nA_{n}^{\ast }V_{n}(x)\right\Vert _{%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n}}^{2}dx\geq C_{n}\int_{0}^{1}\left\Vert V_{n}(x)\right\Vert _{%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n}}^{2}dx\text{ (since }\mathbb{K}_{n}\text{ is onto)}.
$$

Now, I want to find a necessary and sufficient (at least necessary) condition for which  $\mathbb{K}
_{n}$ is onto.

My condition:
$$
\left\Vert nA_{n}^{\ast }\right\Vert _{\mathcal{L}(%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n})}\underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\longrightarrow }l>0\text{ if, and
only if }\mathbb{K}_{n}\text{ is onto.}
$$

Let us start by the sufficient part:

If $\mathbb{K}_{n}$ is not onto, for any $C_{n}>0,$ there exists a sequence $%
V_{n}\in L^{2}(0,1)^{n}$ with $\left\Vert V_{n}\right\Vert
_{L^{2}(0,1)^{n}}^{2}=1$ such that
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1}\left\Vert nA_{n}^{\ast }V_{n}(x)\right\Vert _{%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n}}^{2}dx<C_{n}.  \label{1}
\end{equation}

Take $C_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$ and let $V_{n}(x)=V_{n}\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n}$ such that $\left\Vert nA_{n}^{\ast }\right\Vert _{\mathcal{L}(%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n})}=\underset{\left\Vert V_{n}\right\Vert _{^{%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n}}}=1}{\sup }\left\Vert nA_{n}^{\ast }V_{n}\right\Vert _{%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n}}^{2},$ then clearly this this contradiction since
$$
\left\Vert nA_{n}^{\ast }\right\Vert _{\mathcal{L}(%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n})}\underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\longrightarrow }l>0\text{ and }%
\left\Vert nA_{n}^{\ast }\right\Vert _{\mathcal{L}(%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n})}\underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\longrightarrow }0
$$

For the necessary part we prove that if  $\mathbb{K}_{n}$ is not onto then $%
\left\Vert nA_{n}^{\ast }\right\Vert _{\mathcal{L}(%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n})}\underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\longrightarrow }0.$

If $\mathbb{K}_{n}$ is not onto, we have for any $C_{n}=\frac{1}{n},$ and $%
V_{n}(x)=V_{n}\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n}$ such that $\left\Vert nA_{n}^{\ast }\right\Vert _{\mathcal{L}(%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n})}=\underset{\left\Vert V_{n}\right\Vert _{^{%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n}}}=1}{\sup }\left\Vert nA_{n}^{\ast }V_{n}\right\Vert _{%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n}}^{2},$
\begin{equation}
\left\Vert nA_{n}^{\ast }\right\Vert _{\mathcal{L}(%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{n})}\underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\longrightarrow }0.
\end{equation}

which leads to the desired result. Is this proof is correct?.

Thank you in advance.